# Distance and number of corrected errors in quantum error correction

Tags: error-correction

In Gottesman's introduction, it writes

> A code that corrects t errors is said to have distance 2t + 1, because it takes 2t + 1 single-qubit changes to get from one codeword to another.

Other reviews have slight different definitions but I think they are all equivalent. I am still new to QEC...and a little confused about how these $2t+1$ single-qubit changes take place during quantum error correction..Could anyone give a more detailed explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is answered in the following thread (https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/link-between-distance-of-a-stabilizer-code-and-number-of-errors-it-is-able-to-co). Hopefully the relationship between the distance of a quantum code and the number of errors it is capable of correcting becomes clearer to you after reading the answers provided there.

Comment: Thanks! It's a little weird that I didn't found this question while doing searching..